# Use singletons with data to use in a segment

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am building a segment component in ionic 4, each of the segments has its own component with an own extend controller & service on each component.

Everytime I switch the segments I do a call in the `ngOnInit()` so this will cause to do a call to the api to get the data of the segment.

What is best to do, use singleton data and store this in the service of the component and reuse it. Or is it ok to do a call each time the segment changed?

The data are the restaurant info, restaurant menu and restaurant reviews.

These will change in the future but not necessarily that much to do a call each time you press the segment button.

What is best to do?

This is the segment html:

```
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="restaurantopts" mode="ios" color="primary">
       <ion-segment-button mode="ios" value="info" class="xs-padding-t">
          {{ 'PAGES.RESTAURANT_DETAIL.SEGMENT_BTNS.INFO' | translate }}
       </ion-segment-button>
       <span class="segment-divider"></span>
       <ion-segment-button mode="ios" value="menu" class="xs-padding-t">
          {{ 'PAGES.RESTAURANT_DETAIL.SEGMENT_BTNS.MENU' | translate }}
       </ion-segment-button>
       <span class="segment-divider"></span>
       <ion-segment-button mode="ios" value="reviews" class="xs-padding-t">
          {{ 'PAGES.RESTAURANT_DETAIL.SEGMENT_BTNS.REVIEWS' | translate }}
       </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'info'" class="margin-h s-margin-v">
      <div class="restaurant-info-block">
           <div class="margin-b">
               <mm-body-h>{{ 'PAGES.RESTAURANT_DETAIL.OPENING_HOURS' | translate }}</mm-body-h>
           </div>
           <mm-restaurant-info-block [restaurant]="restaurant"></mm-restaurant-info-block>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'menu'" [ngClass]="(addedToCart) ? 'x5-margin-b' : null">                
        <mm-restaurant-menu  
              [restaurantId]="restaurant._id"
              [restaurantName]="restaurant.Name"
              [checkedIn]="checkedIn"
              (showFooterCart)="displayFooterCart()"></mm-restaurant-menu>
   </div>

   <div *ngSwitchCase="'reviews'" class="tab-reviews margin">
       <mm-restaurant-reviews [restaurantId]="restaurant._id"></mm-restaurant-reviews>
  </div>
```

So `mm-restaurant-info-block` and `mm-restaurant-reviews` has their own controller and service where they call the `fetchData()` method on the init function.

Comment: If you want to reduce the number of fetches, you would save the data result in the service. A timer can be used to fetch for new data once a period of time has passed for new fetches, otherwise reuse stored data.

Comment: @Dan how would you do this timer? Like once a day?

Comment: @Dan how would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `ion-refresher` component in addition to your segment component. That way you can change your segment behavior to only fetch data once for each segment, but let the user manually get fresh data with ion-refresher.

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
   <ion-refresher-content pullingText="Pull to refresh..." refreshingText="Refreshing..."></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>

doRefresh(refreshEvent) {
   // Use the active segment to fetch correct data
   this.loadData(this.restaurantopts, refreshEvent);
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this functionality but at a certain point you want to update data to not fall behind a lot. But thanks for your answer and thinking I appreciate it